# i18n in React with .properties files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

I am in the middle of (large)app rewrite into Reactjs-redux and internalization is next problem.

Ive been looking at some currently available libraries ([redux-react-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-i18n) , [18n-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-react)) but none of them seems to fit.

Why ? Because my localized strings are stored in separate `.properties` files and this **cannot be** changed. But there is a possibility generate whatever format from this in compile time

**Example en_US.properties:**

- key1=This is a constant string
- key2=This is a string with {parameter}
- ....

and similar with de_de.properties file and so on

Also language can be change only on page refresh so this is making it little bit easier

*My question is how to approach this problem. My first naive approach is generate some static constant js object available in app globaly but im feeling thats against javascript best practises also no idea how to deal with parametrized strings*

As im fairly new to javascript id like to hear any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody has same problem
I ended up writing script converting .properties files into json files

Then in React code i created HOC component wich gets keys(or namespaces depends on how you organize your json files) as parameter and fetches values from server
These keys are usually for whole page but sometimes also for single component if it makes sense
All it takes is one more HTTP request you can also cache result

Hop it helps